# tkinter - Widget does not detect entry of mouse when the mouse is held down before entering widget

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent

How can I trigger an event that fires when the mouse enters a widget (e.g. a Frame) while the mouse is held down? It seems that the event in question only fires when the mouse is up.

I'm using this code (approximately) so far:

```
self._root_window = tkinter.Tk()
self._root_frame = tkinter.Frame()
self._root_frame.pack(fill=tkinter.X, padx=5, pady=5)
frame = tkinter.Frame(master=self._root_frame, ...)

self._root_window.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_button_down)
self._root_window.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self._on_button_up)
frame.bind('<Enter>', self._on_mouse_enter)
```

I'm also tracking whether the mouse is down or up using a boolean variable.

How come the `<Enter>` event requires that the mouse is up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make tkinter <Enter> event work when <button-1> is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47944322/7032856).

Comment: I've looked at that and found no clear solution from the answers given there.

Comment: @Nae How would you use find_closest to work around it? I wouldn't be sure when to call find_closest, except whenever I move my mouse.

Comment: You can't. It is defined for canvas. They're pretty much the same questions, but sadly no easy answer yet. Perhaps one can workaround with pointer coordinates.

Comment: With pointer coordinates, this becomes a math problem, something I had hoped to avoid in the first place. :(